# Install Office 2007 using PlayOnLinux (Wine) will not allow to enter CDKEY

Tags: wine, playonlinux, microsoft-office

I just installed Microsoft Office 2007 using PlayOnLinux (a Wine's front end), and it installed successfully, the only problem is that I can't enter the serial number, becouse the text box will not get focus.

Any one had experienced this? Any idea how to solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have Wine as well as PlayOnLinux, here's what you do:

- Go to your Wine's system32 directory (~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32) and rename riched20.dll and riched32.dll so that they're backed up.
- Download RichEdit30.exe (I got it from [here](http://www.findthatfile.com/search-187646-hEXE/software-tools-download-richedit30-exe.htm) or [here](http://media.codeweavers.com/pub/crossover/office/support/richedit30.exe)) and save it to that same system32 directory.
- Run "wine richedit30.exe" and button through the dialogue.
- There should now be two new riched20.dll and riched32.dll files there.
- Copy those two files to your PlayOnLinux system32 directory for Office 2007 (should be at ~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Office2007/drive_c/windows/system32)
- Run one of the Office programs and you should now be able to enter the Product Key.

[source](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/topic-4302-product_key_problem_When_installing_office_2007.html)

Comment: Just to add, in case of wine install without palyonlinux, after installing the RichEdit30.exe, restart the installation and it works seemlessly. Also, the RichEdit30 download is available under
http://www.findthatfile.com/search-187646-hEXE/software-tools-download-richedit30-exe.htm