# Unable to activate MS office 2010 on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit/ PlayOnLinux

Tags: playonlinux, microsoft-office

I have installed MS Office on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit through PlayOnLinux. However I have noticed that the text box in product activation is not enabled. Is there a way to resolve the issue? I Referred the link [Install Office 2007 using PlayOnLinux (Wine) will not allow to enter CDKEY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54761/install-office-2007-using-playonlinux-wine-will-not-allow-to-enter-cdkey) but I am unable to install riched30.dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in PlayOnLinux/ Configure you can find riched20 ,install this one.
You many need ie8 as well, I don't suggest ie6 as install ie6 the program will set your system to windows 2000 and you will have "IOPL not enabled" error

Comment: I found that simply installing IE8 solved the problem